# Save selected option to variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a calculator for a product price.
I created method "calculator" in Products controller.

My question is: how to save selected option to a variable, which i can use next?
In calculator view I put following code:

```
<%= select("product", "product_id", @products.collect {|p| [ p.title, p.id ] }, {prompt: 'Select Product'}) %>
```

So, I select product in selector, and I want to save its id to variable. Next, I want to show product price throught this variable: variable.price.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In controller's action

```
product_id = params[:product][:product_id]  # save product id to a variable

product_object = Product.find product_id # find product using selected product_id 

product_price = product_object.price
```

OR

```
product_price = (Product.find params[:product][:product_id]).price
```

Comment: i will try it. And if i put dynamic information (i can select another option, and it have another price)  in a partion, could i apply AJAX technology to this?

Comment: I placed in controller: @product = Product.find(params[:product][:product_id]). And rails return error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: You either misplaced the code or params[:prduct][:product_id] is not set. 
You should place the code in controller's action where the form is being submitted. Also inspect the params to know exact name of the params where product_id is stored.